# Create custom class using JS in NativeScript and use it in native Android

Tags: android, nativescript

In NativeScript world, is it possible to create a JS file that extends Android's TextView, and then call it natively from pre-existing Android project?

for example, I derived this custom TextView that extends android.widget.TextView:

```
var constructorCalled = false;
var CustomTextView = android.widget.TextView.extend({
    //constructor
    init: function() {
        constructorCalled = true;
        this.setText("set in javascript");
    },
});
```

and now I try to use this class by calling:

```
CustomTextView customTextView = new CustomTextView();
```

in native Android project.

Note: I have gone over this documentation:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/integration-with-existing-ios-and-android-apps/extend-existing-android-app-with-ns-angular2.html
and got it worked, but this example is not enough for me to understand how to construct a custom class in JS and have Java use it freely.

Comment: As a general recommendation - give your extended classes fixed names as the first parameter in an `extend` call, that way you will be able to reach it more easily in your Java code as you won't wonder what the anonymously generated new class's name is. For example if you pass `com.Arzath.custom.CustomTextView`, that will be the object you construct in Java. https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface
https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/how-extend-works.html#the-classname-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pkanev, you have pointed me to the right direction!
So I modified my JS defined class like so:

```
var constructorCalled = false;
var CustomTextView = android.widget.TextView.extend(
  "com.Arzath.custom.CustomTextView",
  {
    //constructor
    init: function() {
        constructorCalled = true;
        this.setText("set in javascript");
    },
  });
```

Next I rebuild my android platform with this command:

```
tns build android
```

That gives me a Java class, CustomTextView in my src folder.

It's important to note that in order to use it, do not forget to initiate the runtime like so:

```
com.tns.Runtime runtime = com.tns.RuntimeHelper.initRuntime(MainActivity.this.getApplication());
        if (runtime != null) {
            runtime.run();

        }
```